# C++ , Why Base class needs a VTable

Tags: c++, virtual, vtable

From my understanding a VTable is necessary to call the most derived version of function. It will have entries about the most derived version of function ... My doubt is why we need to have a VTable for the base class. Since making calls with base object will always need to call the base class functions.

Comment: A vtable is an implementation detail; which implementation are you using? (GCC, Microsoft, Clang, etc.) And why do you say the base class needs one?

Comment: You may want to clarify whether or not you're talking about a base class that participates in, and defines virtual members for,  a polymorphic hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since R Shau didn't like my edit, I provide my answer highly based on his.

VTable is a way to deal with polymorphism. While VTable is a technique widely used by C++ compilers, they are free to provide any other solution.

When a base class has one or more `virtual` member functions, the base class constructor assigns the VTable to an object.

The base class constructor has no way of knowing whether the real object being constructed is a base class object or a derived class object, so base object must keep pointer to point to valid VTable.

Example:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() {} 

    virtual void m() {}

    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() : Base() {}

    void m() override {}

    ~Derived() override {}
};

void foo()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;

    Base * bPtr;
}
```

`bPtr` may point to `Base`

```
    bPtr = & b;
    bPtr->m();
```

or `Derived`

```
    bPtr = & d;
    bPtr->m();
```

Since `bPtr` is of type `Base *`, how to perform polymorphic call `bPtr->m()`, which should result in calling `Base::m()` if `bPtr` points to `b` and `Derived::m()` if `bPtr` points to `d`? Answer: look up for the address of `m()` method in VTable.

What happens when resolving `bPtr->m()` is something like that:

```
   bPtr pointing to Base object
   bPtr-> vtable_pointer -> VTable of Base -> m() -> points to address of Base::m()
   
   bPtr pointing to Derived object
   bPtr-> vtable_pointer -> VTable of Derived -> m() -> points to address of Derived::m()
```

So, without a VTable in base class, polymorphic calls could not be performed because at runtime it is not known if object pointed by `bPtr` is really a base class object or derived class object.

Comment: Solid explanation.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When a base class has one or more `virtual` member functions, the base class constructor assigns the VTable to an object.

The base class constructor has no way of knowing whether the real object being constructed is a base class object or a derived class object.

Example:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() {} 
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() : Base() {}
    ~Derived() {}
};

void foo()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;
}
```

`Base::Base()` gets called directly in the line

```
    Base b;
```

It gets called indirectly, via `Derived::Derived()` in the line

```
    Derived d;
```

How is the implementation of `Base` to know whether `Base::Base()` gets called directly for a `Base` or indirectly for a `Derived`? Without that knowledge, it has to make sure that it's behavior works for both of them -- which means set the VTable for both of them.

Comment: vtable is implementation detail, but I think it is unlikely to be **constructed** by base class constructor.

Comment: @doc, what is a better place to construct a vtable?

Comment: before entering main()? during compile time?

Comment: That's better, however you could still improve this answer :).

Comment: @doc, I am not sure what you are hinting at.

Comment: Nothing specific. Mention that vtable is a way to implement polymorphism, but it is not required as such. I don't get direct/indirect call explained with Base/Derived constructors. Would be better to show it with virtual method.

Comment: @doc, I think it will good for you to create an answer and elaborate on your thoughts.

Comment: This question overwhelms me. I'm off for such questions today :)

Comment: @doc, I reversed your edit because the OP's question is not why there is a need for a VTable for a derived class object but why the base class sets the VTable even for base class objects.

Comment: well, that was explained with `bPtr` pointer. Without the VTable in base class `bPtr->m()` call could not be performed. `bPtr` was of type `Base *`.